# Executing curl statement using subprocess in Python script not working

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

I am trying to run the following curl statement from a Python script in order to upload a file using the slack API:

`curl -F file=@test.csv -F channels=#general -F token=xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx https://slack.com/api/files.upload`

When I run the above command from my terminal, it successfully uploads the correct to file to the #general channel. However, when I try to run it from my Python script using the code below, I get an error message:

```
bash_cmd = 'curl -F file=@test.csv -F channels=#general -F token=xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx https://slack.com/api/files.upload'
process = subprocess.Popen(bash_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stout, sterr = process.communicate()
```

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "trendbot.py", line 75, in <module>
handle_command(command, channel)
File "trendbot.py", line 47, in handle_command
process = subprocess.Popen(bash_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/Users/melanie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/Users/melanie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I print the `bash_cmd` and paste it in my Terminal window, it also successfully runs. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I have to set `shell=True` because my `bash_cmd` is a single string. Now I run the following and it works:

```
bash_cmd = 'curl -F file=@test.csv -F channels=#general -F token=xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx https://slack.com/api/files.upload'.format(file_name, channel)
process = subprocess.Popen(bash_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stout, sterr = process.communicate()
```